# unable to run afterScenario with tag in config.js file for webdriverio cucumberjs framework

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I am working on webdriverio CucumberJS BDD framework. I want to execute some code in afterScenario of wdio.config.js file for scenarios marked with particular tag  eg @setting. I already have below afterScenario setup in my wdio.config.js. How can I run afterScenario with set of code only for particular tags from feature file?

```
/**
 * Runs after a Cucumber scenario
 */
afterScenario: function (uri, feature, scenario, result, sourceLocation, context) {
    if (commonHelper.elements.userMenuLink.isDisplayed()) {
        commonHelper.clickLogout();
    }
    browser.deleteAllCookies();
},
```

I tried to insert below code in above file but it doesnt work

```
let isLastTag;
    
    
    scenario.pickle.tags.forEach(tag => { isLastTag = tag.equals("@settings"); 
    });
    if(isLastTag.contains('settings'))
    {
        console.log('Setting key worked');
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried { tags: @settings} in afterScenario function?

Comment: I tried { tags: @settings}  inside function, but the condition runs for all scenarios instead of running only for feature with tags '@setting' /**
     * Runs after a Cucumber scenario
     */
    afterScenario: function ({tags = '@setting'}, uri, feature, scenario, result, sourceLocation, context) {
        if(tags = '@settings')
        {
            console.log('Done');
        }
        if (commonHelper.elements.userMenuLink.isDisplayed()) {
            commonHelper.clickLogout();
        }
        browser.deleteAllCookies();
    }
}